# Assign an ID on click event

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm trying to make a filterable gallery for my portfolio website, using http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/

```
<button id="Gallery-1" >Gallery 1</button>
```

The idea is when I click on the button for Gallery 1, it will only shows images with class="Gallery-1" (filter: '.Gallery-1')

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#mygallery').justifiedGallery({
        rowHeight : 200,
        lastRow : 'justify',
        margins : 30,
        filter: '.Gallery-1'
    })
})
```

Is it possible to assign the ID of the button that is clicked to "filter"? How could this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `id` of the clicked element:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // etc.
});
```

Then just prepend the `.` to it and you can use it as a class filter:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#mygallery').justifiedGallery({
        rowHeight : 200,
        lastRow : 'justify',
        margins : 30,
        filter: '.' + id
    })
});
```